# Can't inflate Fragments in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-framelayout, skobbler-maps

I am adding a `fragment layout` in my `layout` and in my `fragment layout` is a link address ,when I touch on link I redirect to web Browser but when I back to app get me crash and say can not `inflate fragment` ?

My activity_map.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The main content view -->

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/onebox_fragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        style="@style/left_drawer_list" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and fragment_map.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#80000000">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/map_layout_root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#80000000">

                <com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapViewHolder
                    android:id="@+id/view_group_map"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/chess_board_background"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/map_background">


                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/real_reach_time_layout"
                layout="@layout/element_real_reach_time"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/alt_routes"
                layout="@layout/layout_alternative_routes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/map_styles"
                layout="@layout/layout_map_styles"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/navigation_ui_layout"
                layout="@layout/layout_navigation_ui"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bottom_button"
                style="@style/button_style"
                android:text="@string/navigate"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/position_me_button"
                style="@style/button_style"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/label_position_me" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/heading_button"
                style="@style/button_style"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/label_heading" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/customView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_searchcenter_favorite"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I get log from my app :

When I redirect to web browser the activity go in `onPause()` but when I toch on `software back` restart the activity and don't start activity from `onResum()`.

My MapFragment.java :

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements SKMapsInitializationListener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SKMaps.getInstance().initializeSKMaps(this.getActivity().getApplication(), this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null);
        ((MapActivity) getActivity()).initialize(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLibraryInitialized(boolean isSuccessful) {
        if (isSuccessful) {
            Log.i("LOG", "Success");
        } else {
            Log.i("LOG", "UnSuccess");
        }
    }
}
```

My MapActivity.java is here : [All of code](http://sharjineh.ir/mapactivity.txt)

My crash is :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.asheq.skobb_me_2/com.example.asheq.skobb_me_2.activity.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapViewHolder
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2214)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144)
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5148)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapViewHolder
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
          at com.example.asheq.skobb_me_2.fragments.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:26)
          at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1039)
          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1840)
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5239)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259) 
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5148) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
          at com.example.asheq.skobb_me_2.fragments.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:26) 
          at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699) 
          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885) 
          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057) 
          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1039) 
          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1840) 
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5239) 
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259) 
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5148) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
          at com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapViewHolder.a(SourceFile:254)
          at com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapViewHolder.<init>(SourceFile:159)
          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
          at com.example.asheq.skobb_me_2.fragments.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:26) 
          at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699) 
          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885) 
          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057) 
          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1039) 
          at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1840) 
          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5239) 
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:144) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1259) 
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5148) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_container"
```

Your Fragments go there using a FragmentManager for the Activity and add / replacing to `R.id.map_container`. You don't need to add any other FrameLayout

Don't let the name fool you. It can store more than only maps

If you're trying to load multiple Frames into one view, they must be within the LinearLayout because that's the Activity content and DrawerLayout uses two children.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is here

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapViewHolder.a(SourceFile:254)
```

Fix the NullPointerException in SKMapViewHolder